# debug mode for logging any commands in the sublime console

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I used that command but forgot how to turn it on:

In sublime console, which is invoked by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> I typed something like ...

```
turn_on_debug_mode
```

... and sublime console started to log every command I run. For example, if I press right mouse button on the view and click `Copy file path` then in the sublime console I found logging of this action with the name of invoked command like `copy_file_path`.

So that was an easy way to grab names of commands that I could use in self-written sublime plugins.

The problem is that I do not remember how to turn that debug mode on.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the console input:

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

To view keystrokes:

```
sublime.log_input(True)
```

Comment: Turned on log input but where exactly do I "view" the keystrokes?

Comment: Open the console with `ctrl+\`` or in the menu bar, view -> show console

Comment: How do I set it to enable on startup?